# Updating dependent values recursively

Tags: c++

I'm going to write a hobby C++ app where the interface has lots of places with number inputs/outputs. Some of the values are based on other values. When editing a value, I want to recompute any value that depends on that value. Imagine something like the Blender 3D editor, where updating a value might update a bunch of other values, and those could then trigger more dependencies.

Are there some well known design patterns or, better yet, libraries that deal with this kind of cascading of dependent values? I'm looking for a place to start modeling this kind of behavior in C++.

Comment: Easiest way would probably be registered callbacks wrapped in `std::function` for each object that is "changeable", but there are probably better ways depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: At my workplace, we are actually in the need of a library that does just that as well. In geometric modeling (you are mentioning Blender) this is often called a parametric engine/driver. We decided to build it ourselves. It will likely be open-sourced sometime this year. Basically it's just a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of alternating "feature" nodes (the inputs and outputs) and "compute" nodes. All nodes of the DAG are templates, so that you can connect arbitrary objects and functions, as long as the latter don't mutate their inputs.

Comment: @joergbrech: Cool. Is there a github account I can follow to track when it's released?

Comment: I don't know yet under which github organization it will be hosted, but you could follow my account (joergbrech). Just to danpen your expectations: I don't think we will go open source before fall this year.

Comment: @joergbrech Are you familiar with any OpenSource library that does something similar?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's why we are building our own. You might be able to use something from the rxcpp or qt frameworks, but I am just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for either reactive model or observer pattern.

Observer pattern (from OO-age) requires that the object has some kind of `observe()` method which takes a function (or, in full OO, implementation of a virtual function of an abstract base class), which are collected into some collection (per object!) and, at any mutable operation, all of these methods are called. Ideally, you also provide some kind of `deobserve()`. It's both slow and takes quite much space, but people tend to like it as it's been one of the classic design patterns.

Reactive pattern is based on building a graph (which is usually global to the program or to the calculation). Graph nodes contain functions that can be applied on the input edges; the result is both stored and propagated on output edges. This can be made quite quick and parallelized, but note that intermediate values might depend on calculation path (final values tend to be stable unless nodes have hidden state).